# Stuck on creating a function that will return objects

Tags: javascript

Hi I was wondering if I can get some help here I am stuck. I am trying to create a histogram function that takes an array like ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'] and returns {a:3, b:2, c:1} using the reduce function to build the histogram function. But I am stuck on what the callback function should be.

---

Thank you for any responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce your array like this:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'].reduce(function(obj, value) {
    obj[value] = obj[value] || 0;
    obj[value]++;
    return obj; 
}, {});
```

If your environment supports Object.assign() and ES6 you can also do this:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
    .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, {[b]: a[b] ? ++a[b] : 1}), {});
```

Comment: When i try this it only returns "a". Any chance you can walk me through the logic? Thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 3):

Try to iterate over the array and fill/increment the object's value accordingly,

```
var x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'];
var y = {};

x.forEach(function(itm){
 y[itm] = ++y[itm] || 1;
});
```

Comment: Hi, i was just wondering what does the ++ infront of the y do exactly? I've seen it as counter++ of course. Sorry I'm new.

Comment: @Vget98 That is a pre increment operator. The one that you are talking about is post increment operator. Post increment will return the value first and after that it will do the increment. At the same time pre increment will increment the value first and return it.